# Suggestion box app won't display suggestions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a suggestion box app in JavaScript using AngularJS 1.X that people can post suggestions on and upvote those suggestions. I'm having trouble getting the suggestions to show up on the page. Help? Here's my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Head>
    <title>Suggestion Box</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</Head>
<body ng-app="SuggestionBox" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <h1> Suggestion Box </h1>
    <form ng-submit="addSuggestion()" style="margin-top: 50px">
        <h3> Submit Your Suggestion </h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Great ideas here" ng-model="title"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Suggest</button>
    </form>
    <div class="main" ng-repeat="post in posts"></div>
    <p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" ng-click="upVote(post)"></span> Upvotes: <span id="$scope.posts.upvotes"></span>
    </p>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Olivia\Documents\JS\app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Olivia\Documents\JS\controllers\HomeController.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Olivia\Documents\JS\Services\Suggestions.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'suggestions', function($scope, suggestions) {
    $scope.helloWorld = "Hello, AngularJS!",
    $scope.posts = Suggestions.posts,
    $scope.addSuggestion = function($scope.title) {
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === "") {
            return;
        };
        $scope.posts.push({
            title: $scope.title,
            upvotes: 0,
        });
        $scope.title = '';
    }
    $scope.upVote = function(post) {
        $scope.posts[post].upvotes += 1;
    };

}]);
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('SuggestionBox', ['ngRoute']);
```

I haven't added any routing yet so the route is just sitting there

Suggestions.js:

```
app.factory('Suggestions', [function(){
    var demoSuggestions  = {
        posts: [
            {
                title: 'Insert suggestion here', 
                upvotes: 10,
                comments: [],
            },
            {
                title: 'See above',
                upvotes: 2,
                comments: [],
            },
        ]
    };
    return demoSuggestions;
}]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide more information? What does not display? You define your SuggestionBox by using angular.module and add ng-app="SuggestionBox" to your body. If you open the browser and check the dev tools, do you see your form?

Comment: `src` should point to your root folder location, e.g. `<script src="JS/app.js"></script>`, as you need to launch your app in a local server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working version. It looks like you're pretty new to AngularJS. Feel free to ask any questions.

```js
"use strict";
var app = angular.module('SuggestionBox', ['ngRoute']);

app.factory('SuggestionsFactory', [function () {
    var posts = [
        {
            title: 'Insert suggestion here',
            upvotes: 10,
            comments: [],
            id: 1
        },
        {
            title: 'See above',
            upvotes: 2,
            comments: [],
            id: 2
        }
    ];
    function postFactory(title) {
        return {
            title: title,
            upvotes: 0,
            comments: []
        }
    }
    var getPosts = function(){
        return angular.copy(posts);
    }
    var addPost = function (title) {
        posts.push(postFactory(title));
    }
    var removePost = function(id){
        // remove from posts by id
    }
    return {
        getPosts: getPosts,
        removePost: removePost,
        addPost: addPost
    }
}]);

app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'SuggestionsFactory', function ($scope, SuggestionsFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.posts = SuggestionsFactory.getPosts();
    vm.title = '';
    vm.addSuggestion = function () {
        if (vm.title && vm.title !== '') {
            SuggestionsFactory.addPost(vm.title);
            vm.posts = SuggestionsFactory.getPosts();
            vm.title = '';
        }
    }
    vm.upVote = function (post) {
        post.upvotes += 1;
    };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="SuggestionBox" ng-controller="HomeController as vm" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1> Suggestion Box </h1>
            <ng-form style="margin-top: 50px">
                <h3> Submit Your Suggestion </h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Great ideas here" ng-model="vm.title" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.addSuggestion(vm.title)">Suggest</button>
            </ng-form>
            <div class="main" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts">
                <p style="font-weight:bold;">{{post.title}}</p>                
                <div>
                    <button ng-click="vm.upVote(post)">upvote</button> Upvotes:
                    <span id="upvotes">{{post.upvotes}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```